# Firebase- Sigin with Twitter shows Your browser in no longer supported

Tags: android, firebase-authentication

Twitter sigin from android app when twitter app in not installed is working.

But when we Click on Signup it shows that your browser is no longer supported.

Login is working fine but when i click on signup button message is displayed "Your browser `javascript` is disabled & your browser is not supported"

```
TwitterAuthConfig authConfig =  new TwitterAuthConfig(
                getString(R.string.twitter_consumer_key),
                getString(R.string.twitter_consumer_secret));
        TwitterConfig twitterConfig = new TwitterConfig.Builder(this)
                .twitterAuthConfig(authConfig)
                .build();
        Twitter.initialize(twitterConfig);
mLoginButton.setCallback(new Callback<TwitterSession>() {
            @Override
            public void success(Result<TwitterSession> result) {
                Log.d(TAG, "twitterLogin:success" + result);
                handleTwitterSession(result.data);
            }
            @Override
            public void failure(TwitterException exception) {
                Log.w(TAG, "twitterLogin:failure", exception);
                updateUI(null);
            }
        });
private void handleTwitterSession(TwitterSession session) {
        AuthCredential credential = TwitterAuthProvider.getCredential(
                session.getAuthToken().token,
                session.getAuthToken().secret);
        mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:success");
                            FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                            updateUI(user);
                        } else {
                            // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                            Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential:failure", task.getException());
                            Toast.makeText(TwitterLoginActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            updateUI(null);
                        }

                    }
                });
    }
```